# get content of notepad and post on html and also edit it

Tags: php, javascript, notepad

is there a way to get a content of an html page or notepad, then display in on my html page to edit and save, where the edits will be permanent and also allow me to view the content like an individual page or in my desktop. using php or javascript?

or to simply put it embed a notepad on my page where i could edit it anywhere i am.

Comment: You can't edit files on client machine. But you may do whatever you want with files located on server using file manupulation functions of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open and edit text documents in a browser, using stuff like:

- [ACE editor](http://ace.ajax.org/);
- [Tiny MCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

The idea is that you open desired file via php [[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)], put its raw data into a `<textarea>` and enhance it with aforementioned plugins.

Then once you submit your edit, you store new raw data into file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php `fopen` function and read the content of the file and load it in `texteditor` and using `fwrite` function save the content

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you're wanting a [personal wiki](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/technology/the-quick-dirty-guide-to-personal-wikis.html); wiki engines are built to be user-editable online (and permanently saved after you edit). A personal wiki is just a wiki that only one user uses or has access to.

If you have a server and don't mind having to be online to edit your notes, any wiki software (like [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)). If you want your notes to go with you, even offline, try [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/), a one-page wiki built in javascript so it's all one HTML file.